# Rendering component on runtime after Http request in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, vue-component

I'm trying to conditionally render a component in VueJS after an Http request right away when the application starts. If the response is ok I would like to render component 1, otherwise component 2. I would also like to render the component onClick

App.vue

```
<template>
   <div id="app">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">



      <div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample05">
        <ul class="navbar-nav pl-md-5 ml-auto">
          <li v-for="tab in tabs" v-bind:key="tab" v-bind:class="['nav-item nav-link', { active: currentTab === tab }]"
            v-on:click="currentTab = tab">
            {{ tab }}

          </li>

        </ul>


      </div>

    </nav>

    <component v-bind:is="currentTabComponent" class="tab"></component>

  </div>
</template>

<script>

import Comp1 from '../components/comp1'
import Comp2 from '../components/comp2'


export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Comp1,
    Comp2
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      currentTab: 'Comp2',
      tabs: ['Comp1', 'Comp2']
    };
  },
    computed:{
        currentTabComponent: function () {
            function check(){
                fetch('someHttpUrl')
                    .then(response => response.json())
                      .then(data => {
                            resolve('Comp1')
                        });
                .catch(err => {
                    resolve('Comp2')
                })
            }
            var result = check();
            result.then(async function (data) {
                return data
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

When I click on the tab, the right component is loaded. But not when the application starts.
Is there any Vue method to render asynchronous a component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to have `currentTabComponent` computed method.

You can just make your HTTP call and update `currentTab` when it is done.

Something like this:

```
mounted() {
  fetch('someHttpUrl')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    this.currentTab = 'Comp1'
  });
  .catch(err => {
    this.currentTab = 'Comp2'
   })
}
```

I also removed the method named `check` as it seemed redundant.